# QEMU guest can access HTTPS sites, but not HTTP

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, libvirt, qemu

So I'm configuring a QEMU guest on my Debian Wheezy server,
using virt-manager.

As guest I've installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 server.

The server contains the following iptables rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3080
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3080
```

This was taken from the serverfault question "[How to run a server on port 80 as a normal user on Linux?](https://serverfault.com/questions/112795/how-can-i-run-a-server-on-linux-on-port-80-as-a-normal-user)"

So incoming HTTP requests on port 80 to the Debian host are being redirected to the correct application.

But, as a side effect, outgoing requests from my QEMU guest are also being redirected there.
How can I fix that?

Comment: What sort of server is this? What about the network it's on? Any firewalls, etc?

Comment: It's basically a clean Debian server install with no firewall.

Comment: as I see **http: //www.google.be/** redirects to **https ://www.google.be/** that is the reason it is not able to wget the URL try some url like **http:// serverfault.com/** and see if that helps.

Comment: I've found the culprit: an iptables rule, I'll update the question

Comment: Hm, not really clean, then, is it? :)

Comment: Well, I'll refer to the 'basically' in my statement in order to save some face :)

Answer (score 0):

The rule

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3080
```

means redirect **everything** with destination port 80 to port 3080 and that matches all the HTTP traffic. You'll need to put an IP address or an interface in order to be specific: if your IP address is 1.2.3.4, this will do:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3080
```

The `-d 1.2.3.4` flag specifies destination address and only requests to your IP will be redirected.

Another option is to use the network interface, so if your internet connection is on `eth0`, you can use:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3080
```

Which also would work because `-i` matches **incoming** traffic on the `eth0` interface, e.g. requests made to your computer.

You can even combine the filters (e.g. you have multiple NICs and multiple IPs, but you want to run the site only on a single pair)

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -d 1.2.3.4 -p tcp -j REDIRECT --to-port 3080
```

You should consult the iptables manual if you need fine control over who gets redirected, gets blocked, etc.