# What is the best way to redirect port 80 connections to port 8080 with ipv6?

Tags: nginx, web-server, ipv6

As I understand it, IPV6 is supposed to get rid of this whole port forwarding requirements. However if I want to host a web server on port 80 with something like python or javascript i'd still need to use sudo which is meant to be bad practice.

So as a workaround im attempting to use nginx to redirect port 80 requests to port 8080 so I can just host the webserver on port 8080 without the need of sudo and users can see it without needing to access a specific port. However when doing this I keep on getting a bad gateway error from nginx and i'm unsure what im doing wrong.

Im quite new at all of this so i'd appreciate any guidance.

Here is my nginx config file, its quite simple but I was hoping it would do the trick:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name domainname.com;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass              http://[ipv6:ipv6:ip:ipv6:ipv6:ipv6:ipv6:ipv6]:8080;
    }
```

}

Comment: You want an arbitrary user to be able to run a public service? *That* could be a bad practice. On the other hand, using `sudo` to grant the right to control a system service (a web server) to selected users is actually considered to be a *good* practice. All in all, this looks like XY problem; what is *original* problem you are hoping to solve this way?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov mhm I guess that makes sense. I guess the logic is that if you're running the webserver with sudo then someone attacking it might have sudo rights? Like I said im quite new to all this so im just going off what i've learnt looking at similar posts. I don't really mind running it as sudo. The reason I went back to it is because I don't have direct access to the server and I wanted it to run on port 80 on startup. This would require password input, and the person turning it on wouldn't be able to input it since its headless, and ideally I don't wanna ssh into it everytime.

Comment: If you don't want to SSH or otherwise access some server's management shell, how are you going to start or control any service on any port? (E.g. when you update files of your "python" or "javascript" service, you'll need to restart it somehow. On the server.) If you need it to just start at boot, you'll just configure it to start at boot, once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elsewhere on Server Fault (and other Stack Exchange sites) you can find more complete answers of options for low-numbered unprivileged ports.

For Linux, I prefer [authbind](https://serverfault.com/a/112805/241174), a hack where a setuid privileged helper does this specific port thing.  Then put the authbind program in front of the web server software, in the command you start in your service manager.

Another option with different pros and cons, Linux [CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE](https://serverfault.com/a/112799/241174).

---

Some more precision might help your understanding about IP networking and user security.

IPv6 removes IP address scarcity. You don't need to worry about any other host needing port 443. Making port sharing at the network firewall obsolete.

However you still need to deal with privileged ports. A legacy concept to prevent any random user from starting say a ssh server on that well known port. However, least privilege is better, and you should be managing this user, so its fine.

Regarding users, sudo isn't bad, its complicated. Switch user programs exist to allow people to cross user based privilege isolation, in specific situations. Problem is, the policy people tend to write gives far too much privileges. Running any command as root is far more powerful than just the web server as root, that user owns your server.  Even if you restricted the command correctly, if the user can replace the program with a malicious one, they now can do anything as root.  In contrast, my suggestions are to allow only the port thing, via a shim or capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly comment....

> without the need of sudo

...is not a good basis for designing your infrastructure. Privileged ports are that way for a reason. What you are proposing here does undermines the good practice of security tiering. The most exposed parts of your host should use the most robustware. If the origin server was nginx, lighttpd, apache or IIS then that probably wouldn't be an issue. "something like python or javascript" *is* an issue / shouldn't be exposed.

> I keep on getting a bad gateway error from nginx

Rather than start addressing that here, perhaps you should post a new question asking how to diagnose and resolve this. You should include details of what happenned when you tested a http request to the origin server from the host where nginx is running.

Comment: Low numbered ports being privileged does not imply that the software stack providing the IP service is of any particular quality. nginx started as root might be ancient and unpatched. Some http server in Python started as some not-root user (tornado.httpserver perhaps) could be well maintained. Or you could start nginx as not-root. Naturally you will need to trust non privileged users more if they can start web servers, but when no people and only the automation user can log into a host, that may be acceptable.

Comment: You've got it back to front. Yes, changing the port number does NOT change the quality of the software, and leaving aside the additional functionality for managing http traffic in nginx / apache httpd /  lighttpd / etc its simply the more sets of eyes issue.